# NodeJs - How to convert chunks of data to new Buffer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

In NodeJS, I have chunks of data from a file upload that saved the file in parts. I'd like to convert this by doing new Buffer() then upload it to Amazon s3

This would work if there was only one chunk but when there are multiple, I cannot figure out how to do new Buffer()

Currently my solution is write the chunks of data into a real file on my own server, then send the PATH of that file to Amazon s3.

How can I skip the file creation step and actually send the buffer the Amazon s3?

Comment: i was not able to do what you are asking. i solved it by writing to disk. then by getting the file size because s3 uploads dont work with steams that are too small as you mentioned. if the file size is under 1 MB i read the file back into RAM again, upload to S3. If the file size is greater than 1MB, I would do fs.readFile and upload the resulting stream in the body as a binary buffer and that worked for me. i was unable to escape saving the file locally - however, saving locally is not a bad thing since your ec2 instance can just quit when you upload a really big image and you run out of RAM

Answer (score 0):

i guess you need to use **streaming-s3**

```
var streamingS3 = require('streaming-s3');
var uploadFile = function (fileReadStream, awsHeader, cb) {

    //set options for the streaming module
    var options = {
        concurrentParts: 2,
        waitTime: 20000,
        retries: 2,
        maxPartSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
    };
    //call stream function to upload the file to s3
    var uploader = new streamingS3(fileReadStream, aws.accessKey, aws.secretKey, awsHeader, options);
    //start uploading
    uploader.begin();// important if callback not provided.

    // handle these functions
    uploader.on('data', function (bytesRead) {
        console.log(bytesRead, ' bytes read.');
    });

    uploader.on('part', function (number) {
        console.log('Part ', number, ' uploaded.');
    });

    // All parts uploaded, but upload not yet acknowledged.
    uploader.on('uploaded', function (stats) {
        console.log('Upload stats: ', stats);
    });

    uploader.on('finished', function (response, stats) {
        console.log(response);
        cb(null, response);
    });

    uploader.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Upload error: ', err);
        cb(err);
    });

};
```

Comment: This wouldn't solve my problem because Amazon s3 has a 5 MB minimum limit. My chunks are about 2 MB in size each. Whether or not I use this method, I still have to combine my chunks into a chunk that's at least 5 MB.

Is there a way to combine chunks into a larger chunk or create a buffer out of multiple chunks??